# Regular Expressions In Compilers

Tags: regex, compiler-construction

Are regular expressions used directly in compilers to identify tokens?

Comment: Depends on the compiler.

Comment: "compilers" is just a little bit too generic, since there are dozens of languages and every language has >= 1 compilers.

Comment: "used in" is also too vague. There are meta-compilers that will take a language definition and output, say, C-code for parsing files like that. If the meta-compiler accepts regexps but outputs a state machine, are regexps "used in" that compiler?

Comment: @drysdam: yes they used in such a compiler. @Rudie: I don't see the problem. There are many compilers. Some use REs, some don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Many compilers use a generated scanner whose token rules are defined as REs to a DFA. Flex(1) is a prominent example.

I don't understand the second part of your question.